# number of connected users in a specific database in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find how many users are conected to a specific database.
I used a counter that count every time that there is a new created connection.
the connection happens when the user enter a right username and password

```
counter=0
Flag = FindConnection(username , password) 
if Flag == True:
   counter +=1
```

FindConnection function returns true and make connection if the username and password are right, otherwise it returns false.
Is there any other way to count the number of users???

Comment: If you want to know the number of users connected to the database, you should ask the database. It you want to know something else, you should improve your description. It is not clear.

Comment: how i can ask the database??  becuase this is what i am trying to find

Comment: Consult the documentation of the database. We can't help since you did not even tell us which db you are using.

Comment: i am using a normal database have .mdb extention

Comment: You mean like an Access database file?

Comment: Then you can not get it from there. To be aware of connections it need a real database server. The only way to do that properly is to query the processes that opened the file from the OS. But I guess you are on Windows and I'm not the Windows guy and can't tell you how.